# css float and border problem

Tags: css, css-float

I got this css:

```
.post-user {
    background:black;
    color:white;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}
.img-side {
     border-style:solid;border-width:medium;width:75px;margin-bottom:2px;
}
.top-head {
    background:cyan;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
}
.main-box {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    display:block;
    height:auto;
}
```

And html looks such :

```
<div class="main-box">
    <div>
        <div class="top-head"><span>At top</span>
        </div>
        <div class="side">
            <div class="img-side">
                <img src="http://st2.gsmarena.com/vv/pics/htc/htc-snap-1.jpg" width="75px" height="75px" />
            </div>
        <div class="post-user">User name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/PGFTz/)

But the div `post-user` is going outside the border.

How can i fix it ?
(P.S. : Its something similar to layout of forums)

Comment: Both Andrew's and Ben's answers will work and both have their drawbacks. Neither is the win-all solution so make an educated decision here as to what path you want to take.

Comment: @benjamin ah its not that easy u have to wait a certain amount of time. I wasnt able to accept at that time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PGFTz/5/ I added a clear fix after `post-user` which allows it to stay within the box.

Answer (score 6):

add `overflow:hidden` to your `.main-box` css

extensive explenation about how and why it works can be found here

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

A great guide for the working of float can be found here:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

Comment: Sorry this answer works perfectly fine but i cant get scorllers if i want. So ill use clear. Thanks ill do +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

You could change `float:left` to `text-align:left`

```
.post-user { 
background:blue; 
color:white; 
width:auto; 
/*float:left;*/
text-align:left;
}
```

That worked for me =)

Comment: yes this works quite fine indeed :> sharp. I am so used to having most elements floating that I suggested the overflow:hidden fixed by default, but in this instance only the post-user is floating

Comment: @Benjamin: Ha, thanks man.  I try to use `text-align` when I can just because it's a bit easier (for me) to understand.  I start to get confused when too many things are `float`ing haha.

Comment: Text is however aligned left by default, so not replacing the float but simply removing it, would also solve the issue. But the post-user will take the entire width instead of only the width it needs to hold the text

Comment: Good point!  I end up using `text-align:left` alot because the sites I've inherited all have a built-in `text-align:center` that I can't change.  So, I often end up thinking `center` is default haha.  +1 on your answer.